# numpy array indexing: different columns of each row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am struggling with np array indexing.

Lets suppose we have an array called a.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((10000,100))
```

And another array called `idx`

```
idx = np.random.randint(low=0, high=a.shape[1], size=a.shape[0])
```

Now what I want to do is to increase every column of a that is in `idx` by one, using a for loop this looks like:

```
for k, i in enumerate(idx):
    a[k][i] += 1
```

Is there anyway to do this using indexing, I know that for example

```
a[:,0] += 1
```

increases every first column of a by one, but how do we do this with different columns?

I hope my question is clear

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((10000, 100))
a[:, 0] += 1
np.random.shuffle(np.transpose(a))
print(a)
```

Explanation:

1. Import the necessary library:

```
import numpy as np
```

2. Define your array of ones:

```
a = np.ones((10000, 100))
```

3. Add `1` to each number in the first column of the array:

```
a[:, 0] += 1
```

4. Shuffle each column of the array:

```
np.random.shuffle(np.transpose(a))
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he is trying to do at all... Basically if the random array is [1, 49, 4] then the loops increments by one the column 1, the column 49 and the column 4. And you can also have twice the same number, e.g. [1, 1, 4, 98, 43, 1] thus resulting in multiple increments.

Comment: @Mathieu As the OP said, their code works, but they want to do it another way. So if you run the OP's code, you will see an array of `1`s, with one `2` in each row at a random position.

Comment: thanks for your answers! I think I should have been a bit more clear that idx was random in this example but not for my actual working example

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the question title it can be done with array indexing.

```
import numpy as np 
a = np.ones((20,10))                                                   

idx = np.random.randint(low=0, high=a.shape[1], size=a.shape[0])
idx                                                                    
# array([5, 0, 7, 3, 8, 7, 5, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 9, 2, 4, 8, 4, 4, 7])

a[ np.arange( a.shape[0] ), idx ] += 1     # Array indexing

a  
# array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2.],
#        [1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
#        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 1., 1.]])
```

`np.arange( a.shape[0] )` corresponds to each row, with `idx` being the column indices.

Comment: thanks! the np.arange part I was missing and thats why I couldnt get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by linearizing the indices (this algorithm is MATLAB-compatible):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((10,5))

col = np.random.randint(low=0, high=a.shape[1], size=a.shape[0])

# linearizing indices: idx = col + row * L; L -> total number of columns
idx = col + np.arange(a.shape[0]) * a.shape[1]
a[np.unravel_index(idx,a.shape)] += 1

print(a)
```

generates

```
[[2. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 2. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 2. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 2.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 2.]
 [1. 1. 1. 2. 1.]
 [2. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 2.]
 [2. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```